# Text wrapping from optparse help string on multiple lines

Tags: python, optparse

I am trying to make my help strings helpful. To do this I have a function `Function()` with a doc string something like

```
def Function(x):
""" First line describing what Function does

Keyword Arguments
x = float -- A description of what x does that may be long

"""
```

Having done this I think have something like this at the end

```
def parse_command_line(argvs):

    parser = optparse.OptionParser()

    parser.add_option("-f","--Function", help=Function.__doc__,metavar="Bs" )

    (options,arguments) = parser.parse_args(argvs)
    return options, arguments

options, arguments = parse_command_line(sys.argv)
```

The trouble occurs when calling the program with `-h` or `--help` The output is line wrapped by OptParse, this means the KeyWord arguments are not started on a new line, is it possible to stop OptParse from wrapping the output or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [optparse is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/optparse), you should consider using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse) instead

Comment: argparse provide same behavior

Comment: Looking through the source code of `optparse`, the answer seems to be no, unless you hack (for example by overriding some internal methods).

Answer (score 0):

In case of interest, I have written two such formatter classes for argparse. The first supports much of the mediaWiki, MarkDown, and POD syntaxes (even intermixed):

```
import MarkupHelpFormatter
MarkupHelpFormatter.InputOptions["mediawiki"] = True
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="""...your text, with mediawiki markup...""",
    epilog='...',
    formatter_class=MarkupHelpFormatter.MarkupHelpFormatter
)
```

The other is called "ParagraphHelpFormatter". It merely wraps text like the default argparse formatter, except that it respects blank lines.

Both are at http://derose.net/steve/utilities/PY/MarkupHelpFormatter.py, and
licensed as CCLI Attribution-Share-alike. They format for ANSI terminal
interfaces. Not highly polished (for example, auto-numbering is unfinished), but you may find them helpful.

Answer (score -1):

argparse provides you with a formatter for raw formatting, ie your lines wont get wrapped
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

optparse also lets you set the formatter.. I suppose you can write your own formatter, but theres nothing provided that i know of